Morita equivalent rings that is not a matrix algebra over the other
I know that the classical example of Morita equivalent rings $R$ and $M_n(R)$, for $n\ge 1$. I want to find some more examples of rings which are Morita equivalent but are not examples of matrix algebras over some ring. I have found this post which asks the same question, but one example which involves K-theory and taking colimits of matrix rings which seems unnecessarily complicated, there is another example involving upper triangular matrices, where it's not fully clear to me why the proposed modules are generators, but otherwise I understand the rest. I am hoping for examples in that vein where the example is relatively easy to describe. It would also be sufficient if one can provide a reference where I can find such examples. Thanks very much.

$M_2(R)$ and $M_3(R)$ are Morita equivalent and not matrix rings of one another. I assume you want to exclude this as well.

Thank you for your clarification, I will write more clearly. I do want to exclude them.

Given any $n$ rings $R_1, R_2, ..., R_n$ and any $2n$ positive integers $r_1, r_2, ..., r_n, s_1, s_2, ..., s_n$, the rings $M_{r_1}(R_1) \times M_{r_2}(R_2) \times ... \times M_{r_n}(R_n)$ and $M_{s_1}(R_1) \times M_{s_2}(R_2) \times ... \times M_{s_n}(R_n)$ are Morita equivalent. So, one should restrict to rings containing no nontrivial central idempotents.

You just need a ring with non-free finitely generated projective modules. On the other hand, Morita equivalence is always realized as being the endomorphism ring of some f.g.p module over the other ring, so they are always kinda close to being matrix algebras.

I'll see if I find the time to write an explicit and interesting example, but I'm sure you can easily find one from a non-trivial bundle over some nice variety.

but are not examples of matrix algebras over some ring. I'm not clear on what this eliminates.  Do you mean full matrix rings?  Otherwise you're eliminating all finite dimensional algebras over fields, which seems kind of drastic.

@MartinBrandenburg Given the right $R$ you can get $R\cong M_n(R)$ for all $n$'s.  It that case $M_2(R)$ and $M_3(R)$ could be considered matrix rings over one another depending on who you ask...  I'm not sure how/if/why one distinguishes matrix rings that are isomorphic to each other in this case :)

@ChanelRose I added a solution at the linked problem because I felt like I knew how to add an answer there better.
